# Vertically align dynamic text div within BX Slider

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I have a BX slider where the background image changes with each slide and there is a div with text on top of the background image.  I would like to vertically center this text div, but it cannot have a specific height since the text is dynamic.

I am also hoping to get it to work responsively across all screen sizes.

I have tried display: table-cell on the `<li>` but it doesn't work with the float:left.  Please see the code on my live site:

You can find [**here**](http://bbmg.com/)  The slider that I am referring to is directly above the footer in the quote area with colored backgrounds.

I am close, but the solution I have come up with requires a height declaration which doesn't work with all of the slides.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your code? Post the code you are having an issue with please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">Your text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent
{
    display:flex;
}
#child
{
    margin:auto; //this will center #child both horizontally and vertically
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks.  It took me a while to get this to work cross browser, but eventually I did with this:
#parent
{
   display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 600px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#child
{
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
 -webkit-flex: none;
 -ms-flex: none;
 flex: none;
 width:90%;
 max-width:900px;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

It's all ;-)